# How do I implement a datatable "group by"?

Tags: c#, datatable

I would like to implement a "Group By" for my datatable. Has any one any suggestions?

update:

c#, .net 2.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499578/c-linq-query-group-by should answer your question, or you could look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the linq extensions in the System.Data.DataSetExtensions assembly:

```
DataTable t = //
var groups = t.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<T>("columnName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [LINQ to DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386977.aspx) and the GroupBy extension methods.

Add assembly System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll to your project to get access to the [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.) extension method.