# How to Group Data in a Data Table (GridView Style)

Tags: c#, .net

For a special requirements, we have created our own HTML table it works like a grid view. It gets its data from a DataTable and populates the TD and TR cells

We want to implement the Grouping functionality just like the grid view, where we specify the column name and all the values are grouped.

How can I perform the grouping directly in the DataTable and then output the rows as it is ? Can I use Linq ? Please help by directing towards an example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750054/how-do-i-implement-a-datatable-group-by/1750412#1750412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try converting your `DataTable` to `IEnumerable` using `AsEnumerable` (make sure you add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions).

Then use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) to group your data. It will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` where each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` object contains a collection of objects and a key. Example:

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy( r => r.Field<string>("someField") );
```

**Update**:
You may group by using multiple fields ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869001/linq-group-by-multiple-fields-syntax-help)) or by nesting them ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442425/nested-group-by-in-linq))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It was helpful. Can I use the same GroupBy to perform multi column grouping. ie. first Group all the values from Column1, then Group all the values from Column2 ?