# Linq to Select First Group

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want a select the first group in the list. Is there a better way to do this.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
var match = (from m in recordList select m).FirstOrDefault();

var matches = recordList.Where(d => d.DateDetails == match.DateDetails);
var lookup = matches.ToLookup(a => a.DateDetails).First();

lookaheadList = lookup.ToList();
```

I'm selecting the first group and pushing it into a second list called lookaheadlist.

My DATA is as follows:

```
DateDetails      Track Details 
0025              ABCD 
0025             EFGH 
0030               XXXXX 
0030               XXXXX
```

Comment: What you mean saying group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `ToLookup`. The lookup groups by different `DateDetails`, but `matches` is already filtered to a single date, so there is already only one group to select.

You could skip the filter and just go with:

```
var match = recordList.ToLookup(a => a.DateDetails).First()

lookaheadList = match.ToList();
```

However, this is redundant for a couple of reasons:

- If you're not storing the result of `ToLookup` and using it to look up other groups by date, there was no point creating the lookup object -- you could have just used [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx).
- If you *only* need the first group, there is no need for any grouping at all (either by `ToLookup` or `GroupBy`).

To directly grab the items that match the first date, use:

```
var firstDate = recordList.First().DateDetails;

var matches = recordList.Where(d => d.DateDetails == firstDate)

lookaheadList = matches.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

> group1 = "025"

and

> group2= "030"

I think you're missing a "group by"

[C# LINQ Query - Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499578/c-sharp-linq-query-group-by?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `GroupBy`

```
var match = (from m in recordList select m).FirstOrDefault();

var firstGroup= recordList.Where(d => d.DateDetails == match.DateDetails).GroupBy(x=> x.DateDetails).Select(x => x.First());
```

and then use `firstGroup` variable to filter that elements

have a read at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337539/ilookuptkey-tval-vs-igroupingtkey-tval#answer-1337567) @Jon Skeet answer about the comparison of ILookup and IGrouping performances

> Bear in mind that ToLookup is a "do it now" operation (immediate
>   execution) whereas a GroupBy is deferred